# Flutter Geolocator doesn't retrieve location without internet or celullar data access

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation

I am using [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package to retrieve the location of the device, however I want to access the location using GPS device only without access to internet or cellular data.

The geolocation apis does not work without internet access and gets stuck in the function forever

```
var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );
```

I also tried using the getPositionStream() but same problem.

It works only if I get the location at least once with internet access then turn it off.

I tested the functionality on multiple Android devices (Xiaomi and Samsung) with multiple different settings (Location Accuracy), (forceAndroidLocationManager) but same problem

Here is the permissions I have

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I tried to remove access coarse location as well as mentioned in the package documentation it may take minutes to get the first coarse location but it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this with many experiences I made and this [github issue](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1312) is that GPS alone needs a clear sky to work and it is not expected to work well inside buildings

Answer (score 0):

It is good way to obtain location data in Flutter using the Google Fused Location Provider and Core Location, which is a framework provided by Apple to manage location services, you can use the `location` package, which provides a Flutter-friendly API to interact with platform-specific location services, including the Google Fused Location Provider on Android. Here's how you can approach using the `location` package to get location updates:

1. **Add Dependency:**
   Add the `location` package to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     location: ^4.1.1
   ```
2. **Request Permissions:**
   Request location permissions from the user. You can use the `permission_handler` package to handle this:

   ```dart
   import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

   Future<void> requestLocationPermission() async {
     final PermissionStatus status = await Permission.location.request();
     if (status.isGranted) {
       // Permission granted, proceed with location updates
     } else {
       // Permission denied, handle accordingly
     }
   }
   ```
3. **Get Location Updates:**
   Use the `Location` class from the `location` package to listen for location updates:

   ```dart
   import 'package:location/location.dart';

   Location location = Location();

   StreamSubscription<LocationData> locationSubscription;

   void startListeningForLocation() {
     locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData locationData) {
       // Handle the updated location data
       double latitude = locationData.latitude;
       double longitude = locationData.longitude;
     });
   }

   void stopListeningForLocation() {
     if (locationSubscription != null) {
       locationSubscription.cancel();
     }
   }
   ```

   Remember to start and stop listening for location updates when appropriate in your app's lifecycle.
4. **Configure Location Accuracy and Options:**
   You can configure the location accuracy and update interval using the `LocationOptions` class:

   ```dart
   LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
     accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
     distanceFilter: 10, // Minimum distance (in meters) between location updates
   );

   location.changeSettings(locationOptions);
   ```
5. **Error Handling:**
   Be sure to handle any errors that might occur during location updates, such as when the user denies location permissions or when location services are disabled.
6. **Dispose:**
   Don't forget to cancel the location subscription when you no longer need location updates to avoid memory leaks:

   ```dart
   @override
   void dispose() {
     stopListeningForLocation();
     super.dispose();
   }
   ```

Remember that the `location` package abstracts the underlying platform-specific location services, which includes using the Google Fused Location Provider on Android. This approach provides a unified way to access location data across iOS and Android platforms in Flutter.

> The Google Fused Location Provider is primarily an Android-specific technology. It is a part of Google Play Services and is optimized for Android devices to provide efficient and accurate location updates by combining various location sources like GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular networks. On iOS devices, the equivalent technology is Core Location, which is a framework provided by Apple to manage location services. Core Location handles location updates, geocoding, and other location-related functionalities on iOS devices.

> In Flutter, the `location` package abstracts the underlying location services for both Android and iOS. When using the `location` package, it provides a unified API for accessing location data regardless of the platform. Under the hood, the package interacts with Google Fused Location Provider on Android and Core Location on iOS. So, even though Google Fused Location Provider itself is Android-specific, when you use the `location` package in Flutter, you can seamlessly get location data on both Android and iOS devices without worrying about the underlying technology differences. Just be aware that the specifics of how the location data is obtained and managed might differ between the two platforms due to the differences in Google Fused Location Provider and Core Location.

Comment: I followed the steps and same problem still occurs, the device can't get the location without internet access or sim card inserted

Comment: while fetching data from global positioning system (GPS)  it will take time to capture the lat lon, you can go to open area and try locating the device.  I have achieve this requirement in java with help of location  manager. you can try implementing that as well.

Comment: Is it that hard to get location depending only on GPS? I mean in terms of time and having access to open area?

Comment: No it is not that hard,

Comment: So we can just assume Location package and Flutter Geolocator package configurations does not take into account this situation of using GPS only if it doesn't get the location?